# How to delay start for x seconds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I've searched around and couldn't quite find the answer. I have two scenes, one with a play button which starts the next scene (the game) and the other scene is the game. Which has a spawner script which spawns random patterns of obsticles. Which can be seen here.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject[] obstaclePatterns;

private float timeBtwSpawn;
public float startTimeBtwSpawn;
public float decreaseTime;
public float minTime = 0.55f;

private void Update()
{
    if (timeBtwSpawn <= 0)
    {
        int rand = Random.Range(0, obstaclePatterns.Length);    
        Instantiate(obstaclePatterns[rand], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        timeBtwSpawn = startTimeBtwSpawn;
        if (startTimeBtwSpawn > minTime) {
            startTimeBtwSpawn -= decreaseTime;
        }

    }
    else {
        timeBtwSpawn -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}}
```

I would like to after the play button is pressed and the game is started there be a delay for 1 second before the spawner begins spawning. I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: um.. set timebtwnsawn to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Unity's Start function as a coroutine directly.

```
private bool _canStart;

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(whatyouwant);
    _canStart = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(!_canStart) return;

    whatyouwant
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a routine that starts after a specific amount of time since the scene was loaded you can use `Time.timeSinceLevelLoad` [this variable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeSinceLevelLoad.html) holds the time in seconds since the last level(scene) was loaded
So you can either create a script that activates your spawner script or add an additional check to your spawner script

Answer (score 0):

You should set timeBtwSpawn before start updating of Spawner:

```
timeBtwSpawn = 1; // seconds
```